# How to create an extension written in C ++ for PHP using static library

Tags: php, c++, makefile, m4

I'm writing an extension for PHP, I didn't have many problems creating the module, compiling, enabling it in Apache and putting the standard example to work.

I modified the default project (added a class with method and property, added information to be displayed in phpinfo, configured to accept c ++, configured the IDE CLion to build the project using commands in CMake) and still had no problems.

My difficulty started when I tried to really use my code, I created a static library (I did the unit tests with cunit, I went through valgrind without any problem) and I tried to use the extension and it doesn't work, I believe the problem is in the configuration of " config.m4 "

If I try to use PHP_CHECK_LIBRARY I get the error message:

```
./configure: line 4787: unset: `ac_cv_lib_nerd4ever-kaya-wrapper_fn_kaya_login': not a valid identifier
configure: error: wrong nerd4eve-kaya lib not found
```

If I directly included the library the project compiles, but has error when trying to load:

```
PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(nerd4ever-kaya-wrapper, 1, KAYA_SHARED_LIBADD)
```

Error in apache when try include library directly

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'kaya' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/kaya (/usr/lib/php/20180731/kaya: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/kaya.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/kaya.so: undefined symbol: _ZN9nerd4ever4kaya9ExceptionD1Ev)) in Unknown on line 0
```

I try check the symbols in my library using the command  "nm -C libnerd4ever-kaya-wrapper.a | less" and the fn_kaya_login is displayed

```
kaya_client.cc.o:
...
00000000 T fn_kaya_login
...
```

My config.m4

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(kaya, whether to enable kaya support,
[  --enable-kaya          Enable kaya support], no)

if test "$PHP_KAYA" != "no"; then
  PHP_ADD_INCLUDE(/usr/include)
  PHP_REQUIRE_CXX()

  PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(stdc++, 1, KAYA_SHARED_LIBADD)
  PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(jsoncpp, 1, KAYA_SHARED_LIBADD)
  PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(curl, 1, KAYA_SHARED_LIBADD)

  KAYA_BASE_DIR="$KAYA_DIR./../.."
  AC_MSG_CHECKING(for kaya base dir)

  if [ test -d "$KAYA_BASE_DIR" ]; then
    dnl nerd4ever-kaya.a
    KAYA_LIBRARY_PATH=`find  $KAYA_BASE_DIR -type f -name "*nerd4ever-kaya-wrapper.a" | head -1 | xargs readlink -f | xargs dirname`

    if [ test -z "$KAYA_LIBRARY_PATH" ]; then
        AC_MSG_RESULT(["libs: not found"])
        AC_MSG_ERROR(["static lib kaya is required"])
    else
        AC_MSG_RESULT(["libs kaya: ${KAYA_LIBRARY_PATH}"])
        PHP_ADD_INCLUDE($KAYA_BASE_DIR/sources)
        PHP_ADD_LIBPATH($KAYA_LIBRARY_PATH)

   dnl    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(nerd4ever-kaya-wrapper, 1, KAYA_SHARED_LIBADD)
   dnl    PHP_CHECK_LIBRARY(nerd4ever-kaya-wrapper, fn_kaya_login,
   dnl    [
   dnl        PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(nerd4ever-kaya-wrapper, 1, KAYA_SHARED_LIBADD)
   dnl        AC_DEFINE(HAVE_KAYA, 1, [ Have kaya support ])
   dnl    ],[
   dnl        AC_MSG_ERROR([wrong nerd4eve-kaya lib not found])
   dnl    ],[
   dnl        -L$KAYA_LIBRARY_PATH -lnerd4ever-kaya-wrapper
   dnl    ])
   dnl    dnl PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH(nerd4ever-kaya, KAYA_LIBRARY_PATH, EXTRA_LDFLAGS)
    fi
  fi
  PHP_SUBST(KAYA_SHARED_LIBADD)
  PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(kaya, php_kaya.cpp, $ext_shared,,)
fi
```